# How to make left join on specific rows in right table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, opencart

My website may have individual price list for user. When I left join imported product table on all products table I don't know where to put `WHERE` which would only do left join on specific rows at right table (logged user rows).

I need to do this in opencart, but it doesnt matter, it's just SQL

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON 
(p.product_id = pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "import i ON (p.ean = i.ean_code) WHERE 
i.import_id = '" . (int)$query->row['import_id'] . "'";
```

I somehow need to do `WHERE` on import table first, but in example above it does it  afterwards. Do I have to execute 2 queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameters where you can.  You need to move the condition to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p LEFT JOIN
     " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd
     ON p.product_id = pd.product_id LEFT JOIN
     " . DB_PREFIX . "import i
     ON p.ean = i.ean_code AND 
        i.import_id = ?
```

You should also be selecting the explicit column names.  This is particularly important in a `LEFT JOIN`, because the tables share column names (at least `product_id`) and you don't know which is referenced by "product_id" in the application code.

Comment: Yeah, `i` is missing, but it works with it, thanks !